# Custom Drawable not generating round corners for CardView's image

Tags: android-layout, android-imageview, android-cardview, cardslib

I created a list of Cards with the new CardView and RecyclerView that look this way:

[image: My card]

I've tried to modify the card with round corners as explained by Mariotti in [this](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/f5a176f1b941200fac68) post.

> PROBLEM: The problem is that, as you can see from the screenshot I am only able to set the card's corner while the image remains squared.

In the example a custom `Drawable` class extending `Drawable` draws a rounded rectangle using `Canvas.drawRoundRect()`, and use a `Paint` with a `BitmapShader` to fill the rounded rectangle with a texture instead of a simple color, as also explained [here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/).

In my Adapter I have:

```
@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    final View itemView = LayoutInflater
                    .from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_card_view, viewGroup, false);
    CardView cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hImage);

    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(itemView.getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    //Default
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        //Default
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    } else {
        //RoundCorners
        madapps.hellogridview.RoundCornersDrawable round = new madapps.hellogridview.RoundCornersDrawable(
                mBitmap,            
             itemView.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cardview_default_radius)
                , 5); //or your custom radius

        cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false); //it is very important

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            imageView.setBackground(round);
        else
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(round);
    }

    //Set onClick listener
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int tag = (Integer) v.findViewById(R.id.hTitle).getTag();
            Toast.makeText(viewGroup.getContext(), "Clickable card no: "+tag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

and I've overridden the value of `R.dimen.cardview_default_radius`to `8dp`, with no result! Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried doing the same, it does not help. If you remove image or move it down you will notice that the card has got round edges. So problem is of the ImageView that is being used. It is difficult to understand that the Image corners leave it's parent!. I have not personally tried this out but perhaps if the top corners of the image were made rounded, it might help.

Comment: I understand your point. Rounding the image itself it is also another way to go. However, the custom `Drawable` class (here: https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/f5a176f1b941200fac68#file-roundcornersdrawable-java) was created to programmatically make the images' corners rounded, as also explained here: http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How you solve this problem?

Comment: check my last answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it using this:

https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView

and applying a radius of `10dp` (same as the card) to the top corners of the image:

```
<com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView  android:id="@+id/headerImage"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cardbackground3"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="10dip"
    app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="10dip"
    app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="0dip"
    app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="0dip"
    app:sriv_border_color="#333333"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks thats exatly what I need. But you know there is one problem know.  There is little space like padding between borders of CardView and Image. But there was no paddings in my case. It seems to mе that this library rounded corners but dont change position of image. Do you have the same think? By the way my layout the same as yours. Do you have any ideas about that?

[image]

Comment: Thats my bad. I forgot about                             setPreventCornerOverlap(false) Now its normal.